# on window scroll primeNg dropdown menu list should close

Tags: angular

I want to close primeNg dropdown menu list, on window scroll.

```
 @ViewChild("hideMenu", { static: false }) hideMenu: DashboardComponent;
  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
     this.hideMenu.click();
  }
<div #hideMenu>
<p-dropdown [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar1" editable="true" placeholder="Select a Brand"></p-dropdown>
<p-dropdown [options]="cars1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar1" editable="true" placeholder="Select a Brand"></p-dropdown>
<p-dropdown [options]="cars2" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar1" editable="true" placeholder="Select a Brand"></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

I tried but not working, Please suggest

Thanks

Also how to detect scroll event with `nb-card`

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>
    <span class="float-left">IRO Dashboard</span>
    <!-- <span class="float-right"
      ><button (click)="generatePdf()">Download</button></span
    > -->

    <span class="float-right">
      <button
        type="button"
        nbButton
        status="primary"
        shape="round"
        routerLink="/smspages/iro/add-iro"
      >
        Add New IRO
      </button></span
    >
  </nb-card-header>

  <nb-card-body *ngIf="loader">
    <div class="loadercont">
      <div class="loader">
        <div class="reverse-spinner"></div>
      </div>
      Loading...
    </div>
  </nb-card-body>

  <nb-card-body *ngIf="viewDashboard">
    <p-table
      #dt
      [columns]="cols"
      [value]="IroDashboardData"
      selectionMode="single"
      (click)="showreportsbtn(selectedIRO)"
      [(selection)]="selectedIRO"
      [paginator]="false"
      [rows]="10"
      [scrollable]="true"
      scrollHeight="330px"
      rowHover="true"
    >
      <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
        <div class="divBg">
          <div #action class="theader" *ngIf="export_flag">
            <div>
              Action on selected row:
              <span>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  nbButton
                  status="primary"
                  shape="round"
                  size="tiny"
                  (click)="generateIRODetails()"
                  outline
                >
                  Export EXCEL
                </button>
              </span>
              <span>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  nbButton
                  status="primary"
                  shape="round"
                  size="tiny"
                  (click)="generatePdf()"
                  outline
                >
                  Export PDF
                </button>
              </span>

              <!-- <span>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  nbButton
                  status="primary"
                  shape="round"
                  size="tiny"
                  (click)="exportIO(selectedIRO)"
                  outline
                >
                  Export IO
                </button>
              </span> -->

              <span
                ><button
                  type="button"
                  nbButton
                  status="primary"
                  shape="round"
                  size="tiny"
                  (click)="EditIRO(selectedIRO)"
                  routerLink="/smspages/iro/edit-iro"
                >
                  Edit IRO
                </button></span
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [style.width]="col.width">
            {{ col.header }}
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
            <p-multiSelect
              *ngSwitchCase="'username'"
              [options]="salesperson"
              defaultLabel="All"
              (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')"
              maxSelectedLabels="1"
            ></p-multiSelect>
            <input
              *ngSwitchCase="'iro_id'"
              pInputText
              type="text"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')"
            />
            <input
              break-word-container
              *ngSwitchCase="'ro_no'"
              pInputText
              type="text"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')"
            />
            <input
              *ngSwitchCase="'total_amount'"
              pInputText
              type="text"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')"
            />
            <input
              *ngSwitchCase="'campaign_name'"
              pInputText
              type="text"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')"
            />
            <p-multiSelect
              *ngSwitchCase="'iro_status'"
              [options]="irostatus"
              defaultLabel="All"
              (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')"
              maxSelectedLabels="1"
            ></p-multiSelect>
            <input
              *ngSwitchCase="'campaign_start_date'"
              pInputText
              type="text"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')"
            />
            <!-- <nb-datepicker #campaign_start_date></nb-datepicker> -->
            <input
              *ngSwitchCase="'campaign_end_date'"
              pInputText
              type="text"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')"
            />
            <!-- <nb-datepicker #campaign_end_date></nb-datepicker> -->
          </th>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
          <td
            *ngFor="let col of columns"
            [style.width]="col.width"
            [style.word-wrap]="col.break"
          >
            {{ rowData[col.field] }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

Comment: did you check my solution??

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution like below

```
<nb-card #hideMenu (wheel)="myFunction()"></nb-card>

         <p-multiSelect
              *ngSwitchCase="'username'"
              [options]="salesperson"
              defaultLabel="All"
              (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')"
              maxSelectedLabels="1"
              (onClick)="multiselect()"
            ></p-multiSelect>




scrollingPreviousValue: number;
  scrollingCurrentValue: number;

  @ViewChild("hideMenu", { read: ElementRef, static: false })
  hideMenu: ElementRef;

 multiselect() {
    this.scrollingPreviousValue = this.hideMenu.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  }
  myFunction() {
    this.scrollingCurrentValue = this.hideMenu.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
     if (this.scrollingCurrentValue != this.scrollingPreviousValue) {
      this.hideMenu.nativeElement.click();
      //this.hideMenu.nativeElement.style = "display: none";
      // this.renderer.setStyle(this.hideMenu.nativeElement, "display", "none");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hide() function of Primengdropdown.

In properties section use view child to get reference:  `@ViewChild('dd') dropdown: Dropdown;`

In onWindowScroll, check if panel is visible then call hide() on reference

```
 @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll() {
     if(this.dropdown.panelVisible){
         this.dropdown.hide();
     }
  }
```

Stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-wz4zij

Comment: Thanks for issue but i can't detect scroll event in nb-card, whiich mmentio above .